# Can't add PHP inside of JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to add a PHP code to echo a text inside of JavaScript but when I try the code it's don't echo the text it echoes 0

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    <?php if (empty($dark_mode)){ echo '$('*').toggleClass("light") document.getElementById("*").classList.remove("dark");';}else{ echo '$('*').toggleClass("light")  document.getElementById("*").classList.remove("light");';} ?>
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same issue on past i did use php to print all javascript with php vars too , in your case it well be :

```
     <?php
     echo "<script>";
     echo "window.onload = function(){";
     if (empty($dark_mode)){
              echo "$('*').toggleClass('light') document.getElementById('*').classList.remove('dark');";
     }else{ 
     echo "$('*').toggleClass('light') document.getElementById('*').classList.remove('light');";
     }
```

echo "";
?>

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error with your quotes - there are several singlequotes that arent' escaped, so PHP suddenly gets an unexpected `*`.

```php
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    <?php if (empty($dark_mode)){ echo '$('*').toggleClass("light") 
 // -----------------------------------^^^^^^^ See the mismatch of quotes here
document.getElementById("*").classList.remove("dark");';}else{ echo '$('*').toggleClass("light")  document.getElementById("*").classList.remove("light");';} ?>
};
</script>
```

You can solve this a few ways, one is by using double-quotes or escaping the single quotes, but you can simplify this quite a bit by just setting a variable in PHP and using that instead of doing the same thing inside the conditions.

```php
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    // Remove both dark and light
    $("*").removeClass("dark light");
    // Add current mode based on $dark_mode in PHP
    $("*").addClass("<?php echo empty($dark_mode) ? 'light' : 'dark'; ?>");
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer Heredoc syntax to echo multiple lines of dynamic JavaScript/jQuery code. You don't need to escape any quotes and it's easier to read, especially when you have dozens of lines of code.

```
$if_script_code = <<<if_script
Here goes the script code 
    for better readability
    and without the need to
    escape a ton of quotes.
if_script;

$else_script_code = <<<else_script
more script code
here...
else_script;

if ($my_condition === TRUE) {
    $script_code = $if_script_code;
    }
else {
    $script_code = $else_script_code;
    }
?>
<script>
window.onload = function(){<?=$script_code?>;}
</script>
```

[PHP Manual: Heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)